# how to specify a composite key, in which one key is an identifier and another is not, using fluent nhibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate-mapping, fluent, automapping

I'm trying to specify a composite key, in which one key is an identifier and another is not, using fluent nhibernate. Is it possible in fluent? If yes, what I'm doing wrong in below mapping?

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<AppUser> mapping)
{
    mapping.Table("AppUser");
    mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "RowID");
    mapping.CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "RowId")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ServerID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a free tool that can help generate the mappings http://nmg.codeplex.com

Also this blog is a great reference guide http://referencenotherdev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html?m=1

You are basically there, you need to remove the id mapping line.